# How to determine in C++ the video driver version?

Tags: c++, graphics, driver

I've got a graphics application that appears to have funky behavior with certain combinations of video cards and drivers.   I would like to capture in the application the version number of the video card driver to help with debugging.    Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: What operating system is your program running on? Hans seems to have assumed Windows.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the operating system. In Windows, you use Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI). There is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that gets the name of the operating system. To get the name of the video driver(s), replace "Win32_OperatingSystem" with "Win32_VideoController" in the example.